chmod doesn't work in docker
ls -la returns -rw-r--r-- for laravel.log
If I run chmod -R 777, or even chmod -R 777 laravel.log, ls -la still reports -rw-r--r--.
Why isn't chmod updating this...
Here is my dockerfile
FROM php:fpm-alpine

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN apk add icu-dev 
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl && docker-php-ext-install intl

RUN docker-php-ext-configure pcntl --enable-pcntl \
  && docker-php-ext-install pcntl;

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
&& docker-php-ext-install zip

COPY ./start.sh /start.sh
RUN chmod +x /start.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/start.sh"]


chmod -R 777 is rarely the right way to fix a permissions problem.

You should not write log files inside a container. Either log to stdout to let Docker handle it or log into a mounted volume.

Appreciate the comments, both good suggestions but none fix the problem.

They are; in general you should not write to files in a container. You are using your container in a bad way.

Write to stdout? I think you're living in another language. I'm using PHP which isn't exactly a runtime application. I'm sure there are other log drivers but stdout doesn't make sense here.

https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/126, summary in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57333444/212107

While this fixes logging, there are other elements that need to be stored such as cache, views, etc. This isn't a way to fix the root problem.

Without more information this can't be answered. Just running a php:fpm-alpine container there is no problem doing chmod anywhere, it just works. How do you run the container? Do you mount volumes? Where and how do you mount them? On which paths do you try to do the chmods exactly? Most information should be included in the output of docker inspect on your container.
